# Big LED matrix controlled by Raspberry Pi

Tags: led

It is possible to attach simple, monochrome Nokia Cell Phone display to rpi and it displays whole graphics to it.

So is it possible to do the same with custom LED matrix (I mean like 41*15 or more pixels, preferably RGB LEDs)? I'm thinking of sth similar to advertising displays.

Comment: I've this http://luisgg79.blogspot.ca/ any others?

Comment: I would recommend using a solution that is ready made, which can read a graphics file. Because making your own massive array, home brew will be extremely difficult. Like the stuff in my answer. Its really nice.

Comment: I've found this http://makezine.com/2014/06/08/megascroller-giant-rgb-led-cylinder-display/

Comment: Marian, that is sick! I love it! I bet it cost a fortune!

Comment: Just for reference - there also exists a solution of constantly making bitmaps to later be sequentially presented on LED screen http://makerflux.com/retro-arcade-gaming-run-on-arduino-brought-to-the-street/

Answer (score 2):

[Here is a project using a several units of smaller LED units to make one big , thing. Nice, old school, maybe some good infor there but generally boring?](http://www.jonshouse.co.uk/ledsign.cgi)

[image]

[But here is another project using RGB LED's, which parse some kind of bitmap file to generate animated graphics.  It is quite possible you can make this even wider or taller.](https://learn.adafruit.com/connecting-a-16x32-rgb-led-matrix-panel-to-a-raspberry-pi/overview)

[image]

> These displays are 'chainable' - connect one output to the next input

[image]

[Like this!](https://learn.adafruit.com/16x32-rgb-display-with-raspberry-pi-part-2)

[image]